# Mouseover Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML :

```
<div class="firstScene">
    <div class="text"> <div class="welcomeMessage">iPhone X</div> </div>
    <div class="pictures">
        <img src="assets/img/iphoneX_off.png" alt="iphone X" id="iphoneX">
        <img src="assets/img/iphoneX_screen.png" alt="screen on" id="iphoneScreen">
    </div>
</div>
```

and this javascript :

```
function initHover () {
  var screen = document.getElementsById("iphoneScreen")

  screen.onmouseover = mouseOver
  screen.onmouseout = mouseOut
}


function mouseOver() {
  var welcomeMessage = document.getElementsByClassName("welcomeMessage")
  welcomeMessage.className += "screenOn"
}
```

I want to add the class "screenOn" on the div with the class "welcomeMessage" but it doesn't work. May someone help me ?

*PS : I don't have the right to use jQuery...*

Comment: where is `initHover` called? where is `mouseOut` defined? adding `screenOn` to `class="welcomeMessage"` will result in `class="welcomeMessagescreenOn"`

Comment: Have you read the instructions on how `getElementsByClassName` works?

Comment: First of all, `document.getElementsById` doesn't exist. What you want is `getElementById`. Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object. `welcomeMessage[0].className += " screenOn"` should be better (don't forget the space before appending your class name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your js code so try to use it know, should work

JS:

```
function initHover () {
  var screen = document.getElementById("iphoneScreen");

   screen.onmouseover = mouseOver
   screen.onmouseout = mouseOut
}


function mouseOver() {
   var welcomeMessage = document.querySelector(".welcomeMessage");
   welcomeMessage.className += " screenOn";
}
```

Note in `mouseOver` function I've changed `getElementsByClassName`, that you used, to the `querySelector` that way you get single object instead of the live HTMLCollection that returned from the `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I've just tried your modifications but it already doesn't work. To display the `#iphoneScreen` I use a `:hover` in CSS with an animation. Should the problem come from this ?

Comment: do you call `initHover` function anywhere in your js file?

Comment: Oh what an idiot I am ! now it works, thank you very much !

Comment: If you've found an answer please check it as an answered.